# iCloudに他のアプリでも参照出来るように保存したい

Tags: swift, swift4, icloud

以下のアドレスのHPや参考書を参照してiCloudにデータ保存をしましたが、保存したものをmacのFinderやiOSのブラウズ等で見えるように保存することが出来ません。

保存に使用しているコードです。

```
DispatchQueue.global().async(execute: {
    if let containerURL = FileManager.default.url(forUbiquityContainerIdentifier: nil) {
        let documentsURL = containerURL?.appendingPathComponent("Documents")
        let fileURL = documentsURL?.appendingPathComponent(self.backupFileName)

        do {
            try strResults.write(to: fileURL!, atomically: true, encoding: .utf8)
        } catch {
            print("write error")
        }
    }
})
```

参考にしたサイト：
[iCloudに保存したテキストファイルで書き込み・読み込み](https://joyplot.com/documents/2016/11/04/swift-icloud-textfile/)

（下記サイトの「iCloudファイルのストレージコンテナ」の項目）
[ファイルシステムプログラミングガイド - ファイルシステムの基礎](https://developer.apple.com/jp/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html)

上記公式ドキュメントに、

> Documentsサブディレクトリ（またはそのサブディレクトリの1つ）内のすべてのファイルまたはファイルパッケージは、
>   個別に削除できる独立したドキュメントとして（OS XとiOSのiCloud UIを通じて）ユーザに表示されます。

とあります。これはMacのFainderのiCloud項目などで見えるという意味ではない？

どのようにしたら良いのか、または解説のあるページ、何でも良いので教えていただけたら幸いです。

よろしくお願いいたします。

追記：もしかすると、このあたりが関係するのでしょうか？
[DocumentBrowser を使ったアプリの実装方法](http://amarron.blog/detail.php?id=20170826)
[System-Declared Uniform Type Identifiers](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/UTIRef/Articles/System-DeclaredUniformTypeIdentifiers.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

下記ページの方法で、保存したファイルを公開することが出来ました。
とりあえずは公開できたDocumentsフォルダからファイルを手動でiCloudにコピーできるので、アプリで吐き出したファイルを共有したり、バックアップをとれるようになり、ある程度目的は達せました。

[iOS 11ファイルAppにDocumentsフォルダを表示して他のアプリと共有する方法](https://qiita.com/ShingoFukuyama/items/e85d34360f3f951ca612)

info.plistに`Application supports iTunes file sharing`と`Supports opening documents in place`の2項目追加し、値を`YES`にするだけです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

これで`Documents`フォルダーが公開されます。あとは公開したいファイルを`Documents`フォルダーに書き出せばOKです。

ただし、公開したくない物は`Application Support`フォルダーに移動することが必要です。

Comment: リンク切れや内容が大きく更新される場合があるなど、リンクのみの回答はこちらのサイトでは推奨されていません。ご質問の更新部分も多くがリンクばかりなので、結局表題の目的を達成するためには何をどうしたのか、リンクを辿らないとよくわからない状況です。多くの方に大変役立つ極めて有益なQ&Aだと思うので、できれば、設定なりコードなりで重要な事柄だけでも、リンクだけではなく、本文中に御記載いただくようにお願いします。

Comment: ご指摘いただきました点、修正いたしました。